# Calling async method without await hangs in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a background process that maintains a list of indefinitely-running async methods. My expectation is that the below method will start the `ForwardEventsForUser` task, add it to the `_workerList` dictionary, and return immediately.

What's happening when I run in the debugger as well as from a unit test is that it seems to hang on the `ForwardEventsForUser` method and never return.  When I run it without debugging it *seems* to work as expected, although I can't be certain.

Is there something different with how `async` invocations behave in the debugger?

```
public void AddConnection(string userId, string userName)
{
    if (_workerList.TryGetValue(userId, out EventsWorkerInfo? workerInfo))
    {
        workerInfo.ConnectionCount++;
    }
    else
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        // hangs on this line
        Task forwarderTask = ForwardEventsForUser(userId, userName, cts.Token);
        _workerList[userId] = new EventsWorkerInfo(forwarderTask, cts);
    }
}

private async Task ForwardEventsForUser(string userId, string userName, CancellationToken stoppingToken) 
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        nextEvent = await eventService.GetNextEvent(stoppingToken);
        // process the event
    }
}
```

Comment: No, but it's unclear whether `ForwardEventsForUser` itself is truly asynchronous or not, since there's no code. `async/await` won't make a method run in the background. `async` is just syntactic sugar that allows the use of `await` to await already executing tasks without blocking the calling thread

Comment: Do you have a blocking (non async like Thread.Sleep) operation into ForwardEventsForUser ? Try to lauch in a separeted thread via Task.Run( () => ForwardEventsForUser(userId, userName, cts.Token))

Comment: I added the basic body of `ForwardEventsForUser`.

Comment: @BenV And what into eventService.GetNextEvent ?

Comment: It's a `BackgroundService` in an ASP.NET Core API.

Comment: @JérémieLeclercq It ultimately awaits `HttpClient.PostAsJasonAsync`.

Comment: And what does `eventService.GetNextEvent` do? Is that fully async? Basically something somewhere is either doing a synchronous lock or getting itself into a deadlock. So far we can't see what it is

Comment: Change the line where you call `eventService.GetNextEvent` to `await Task.Delay(5000)` and see if it still hangs. If not then as other comments suggest `GetNextEvent` isn't actually async and `ForwardEventsForUser` isn't actually fire and forget but hanging on your while loop.

Comment: I would suggest reading https://blog.stephencleary.com/2020/05/backgroundservice-gotcha-startup.html. This explains well why the code blocks if no callback is scheduled due to async.

Comment: I took your example and converted to a small console app and it seems CancellationToken is never cancelled, so it goes in an infinite loop. how do you cancel your while loop? could you please create a small app to demo it and we can help you. There are a lot of assumptions on this code.